# Sails.js: CRUD functions belong to services or controller?

Tags: model-view-controller, sails.js

I'm new to Sails.js (coming from a PHP background), and I believe it is widely accepted that it's good practice to keep your controllers thin and lean, while services are meant to "do the heavy lifting".

If one should want to perform CRUD functions (not like the blueprint shortcuts thing), and is not interacting with views of any sort, should these CRUD functions belong in `api/services` or `api/controllers`?

Because the structure of a model is inherently linked to the controller, whereas the service should be somewhat standalone and should not reference models by name/structure. Is that correct?

Is it right for a service to be creating objects for multiple models, if it is a secondary effect of a user request? Or should the service return the values to be created back to the controller, and let a single controller create objects for two different models?

Pardon me for my lack of knowledge - coming from PHP, this is a whole new world to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use controller to do a specific things about your model. So your CRUD would be fit in controllers if it has specific function within Model(s).

Use service to do a less specific things, e.g. sending email. Assume that you want to send an email when some model is modified, so the logic that handle sending email should be in service, i.e. you can call it by `someService.sendEmail(params)` inside some model `afterCreate` and `afterUpdate`.

But after all it just a convention, you would learn it as long as you use Sails more. And deeper you get into Sails, you will have your development pattern and environment (not just controller vs. service) that fit to your preference, like using hooks, generator, installable hooks, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My actual use case is actually this: I have an OAuth authentication module which redirects a user to the authentication page, then gets back the access token to create/login a user, as well as update userdata. As Users and Userdata belong to two different models, I'm confused as to whether to make the OAuth a service? Called by the User controller? Then what about Userdata?

Comment: You can learn that by this [reference](https://github.com/kasperisager/sails-generate-auth). I think it's easy enough even for beginner. It leverage oAuth and also storing user data with sails.